# Pandas any 4 consecutive days in last 15 days python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'ID': ['101', '101', '101','101', '101', '101', '102', '102', '102', '102','102', '103', '103', '103', '103','102', '102', '102', '102','102'],
            'product':['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y','x','x','x','x','x'],
            'Week': ['08-03-2019','09-03-2019','10-03-2019','04-03-2019','03-03-2019','11-03-2019','26-02-2019','28-02-2019','06-03-2019','08-03-2019','27-02-2019','01-03-2019', '02-03-2019','03-03-2019','04-03-2019','07-03-2019', '09-03-2019','10-03-2019','11-03-2019','04-03-2019'],
    'Orders': [15, 15, 10, 15,26,15,56, 15,4, 5, 10, 10, 15, 20, 11,10, 15, 20, 11,15]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID','product','Week','Orders'])

df2.sort_values(['ID','product','Week'], ascending= [True, True,True], inplace=True)
```

I'd like to filter the data which has >= 4 consecutive days in last 15 days that there are grouped by ID ,product and Week.

Wanted Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. First we convert the Week column to datetime
2. We calculcate the difference between each date in the given groups
3. We create a count column, because we want 4 consecutive rows
4. Filter on difference 1 and count of 4 to get correct output.

```
# Step 1
df2['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.Week, format='%d-%m-%Y')

# Step 2
df2['Diff'] = df2.groupby(['ID', 'product']).Week.diff().dt.days

# Step 3
df2['Count'] = df2.groupby(['ID', 'product']).ID.transform('size')

# Fill NaN with 1
df2.Diff.fillna(1, inplace=True)

# Step 4
df_final = df2[(df2.Diff == 1) & (df2.Count == 4)].iloc[:, :4]

print(df_final)
     ID product       Week  Orders
6   102       x 2019-02-07      10
5   102       x 2019-02-08       5
4   102       x 2019-02-09      15
3   102       x 2019-02-10      15
11  102       y 2019-02-01      10
12  102       y 2019-02-02      15
13  102       y 2019-02-03      20
14  102       y 2019-02-04      11
7   103       x 2019-02-01      10
8   103       x 2019-02-02      15
9   103       x 2019-02-03      20
10  103       x 2019-02-04      11
```

Comment: Thanks but the code is not working if we change the data. and also you are not checking the last 15 days condition and it should be continuous dates.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame has `Week` column, which is initially of *string* type,
so to facilitate identification of consecutive dates, it should be
converted to *Datetime*:

```
df2.Week = pd.to_datetime(df2.Week, dayfirst=True)
```

Then we should create an auxiliary *Series*:

```
s = df2.groupby(['ID', 'product']).Week.diff().dt.days.fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum()
```

An the last step - actual selection of data:

```
df2.groupby(['ID', 'product', s]).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4)
```

Comment: Thanks we need to add last 15 days from today's condition. and it should be continuous dates. i have updated the data.please check

Comment: I assumed that the source *df* contains data from just this period (last 15 days). If the *df* contains also data from earlier dates, start from filtering out the earlier dates and then proceed just as I described.